# List/query Open X11 Display Connections?

Tags: command-line, x11, utilities

I am hitting this bug: [NEWT errors when closing sketch on Linux · Issue #1651 · processing/processing · GitHub](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/1651), when using `Processing` on Linux (Ubuntu 11.04); my messages are:

```
X11Util.Display: Shutdown (JVM shutdown: true, open (no close attempt): 1/1, reusable (open, marked uncloseable): 0, pending (open in creation order): 1)
X11Util: Open X11 Display Connections: 1
X11Util: Open[0]: NamedX11Display[:0.0, 0xa3b8aa8, refCount 1, unCloseable false]
Finished.
```

The problem is, if I start a Processing program after that, it will usually lock (start with a blank screen); and then I have to re-start again.

So I wanted to go according to the error messages, and try listing these "Open X11 Display Connections" or "NamedX11Display"s on a live system, so I could close them. But it turns out, I have no idea what command tool, if any, to use for this purpose. (Btw, those messages are apparently from the Java `jogl` library).

Is there such a tool, that would query the live state of X11 (as a whole) on a system, and list all open displays and connections? How could I proceed to close one, if the originating process (e.g. `processing`) has already exited the process list?